# Java timer - Anyway to change it to auto start on opening the page rather that clicking start

Tags: java, html, css, web

Instead of clicking start I need it to auto start on opening the page. Also would it be possible to allow to give the user the option to email the time back to them self as it will be used to time how long they took to answer questions

```
<style>
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

    .container {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .timer {
        padding: 10px;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #222, #444);
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 7px solid #efefef;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;

        box-shadow: 
            inset 0 -2px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 
            0 5px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    .cell {
        /*Should only display 1 digit. Hence height = line height of .numbers
        and width = width of .numbers*/
        width: 0.60em;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    .numbers {
        width: 0.6em;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-family: digital, arial, verdana;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        /*Glow to the text*/
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    }

    /*Styles for the controls*/
    #timer_controls {
        margin-top: -5px;
    }
    #timer_controls label {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        background: #efefef;
        font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    }
    input[name=controls] {display: none;}

    /*Control code*/
    #stop:checked~.timer .numbers {animation-play-state: paused;}
    #start:checked~.timer .numbers {animation-play-state: running;}
    #reset:checked~.timer .numbers {animation: none;}

    .moveten {
        /*The digits move but dont look good. We will use steps now
        10 digits = 10 steps. You can now see the digits swapping instead of 
        moving pixel-by-pixel*/
        animation: moveten 1s steps(10, end) infinite;
        /*By default animation should be paused*/
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }
    .movesix {
        animation: movesix 1s steps(6, end) infinite;
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }

    /*Now we need to sync the animation speed with time speed*/
    /*One second per digit. 10 digits. Hence 10s*/
    .second {animation-duration: 10s;}
    .tensecond {animation-duration: 60s;} /*60 times .second*/

    .milisecond {animation-duration: 1s;} /*1/10th of .second*/
    .tenmilisecond {animation-duration: 0.1s;}
    .hundredmilisecond {animation-duration: 0.01s;}

    .minute {animation-duration: 600s;} /*60 times .second*/
    .tenminute {animation-duration: 3600s;} /*60 times .minute*/

    .hour {animation-duration: 36000s;} /*60 times .minute*/
    .tenhour {animation-duration: 360000s;} /*10 times .hour*/

    @keyframes moveten {
        0% {top: 0;}
        100% {top: -400px;} 
        /*height = 40. digits = 10. hence -400 to move it completely to the top*/
    }

    @keyframes movesix {
        0% {top: 0;}
        100% {top: -240px;} 
        /*height = 40. digits = 6. hence -240 to move it completely to the top*/
    }

</style>

<body style="background-color:#000">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- time to add the controls -->
        <input id="start" name="controls" type="radio" />
        <input id="stop" name="controls" type="radio" />
        <input id="reset" name="controls" type="radio" />
        <div class="timer">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers tenhour moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers hour moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers tenminute movesix">0 1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers minute moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers tensecond movesix">0 1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers second moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers milisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers tenmilisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="numbers hundredmilisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Lables for the controls -->
        <div id="timer_controls">
            <label for="start">Start</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start timer with JS code (with jQuery for simplify):

```
// detect page load
$(window).load(function () {

    // get start btn and toggle click on it -> start function must be called
    $('#start').click();

});
```

To send time to  users by email you must save this time in variable, and maybe send it with AJXA to backend (PHP), and there create this email and send it (if your server can do it :) )

P.s. Start something on page without customer - is bad idea, because when customer loads the page - you can't get 100% garantie, that he is on it.
Better to start timer with `click` - only user can make it, and for tests (like in your case) - clicking on buttons will give you better and more accurate results, if you need some for analytics.

Comment: Thanks pal your information was very useful. Do you know what code I will need to Insert to my page im using wordpress, and the plugin to insert java code is CSS & Javascript toolbx.